# Residual variance for glmer model missing

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to calculate the [intraclass correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) for a random intercept model fit with `glmer()` from the `lme4` package in `R`.

Here is how the model looks:

```
model1 <- lme4::glmer(funded ~ 
                          tweeted +
                          `Project Resource Type` + 
                          `Project Subject Category` +
                          `School Poverty Level` +
                      (1 | `School State`),
                      family = "binomial",
                      data = df)
```

Here is the output (fixed effects omitted):

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: funded ~ tweeted + `Project Resource Type` + `Project Subject Category` +  
    `School Poverty Level` + (1 | `School State`)
   Data: df

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 599914.4  600091.2 -299941.2  599882.4    465409 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.2563 -1.2068  0.6538  0.7744  1.3985 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 School State (Intercept) 0.04272  0.2067  
Number of obs: 465425, groups:  School State, 51
```

Beneath `Random effects:`, I expected there to be individual (in this case, an individual project from [Donors Choose](https://data.donorschoose.org/)) `Residual` `Variance` and `Std.Dev.` estimates, as well as the group (`School State`) `Variance` and `Std.Dev.` estimates, but there is not.

Can these estimates be extracted from the output? Is there a reason it is not included? I recognize this may be a statistics-focused question relevant to Cross Validated, but I think because it is related to the output it is appropriate here.

Comment: perhaps useful. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62770/calculating-icc-for-random-effects-logistic-regression

Comment: that is. I may delete this question.